Regex between two specific characters
Text:

John walks to school. He walks past some trees. The leaves on the trees are brown. There are children on bikes. This is a normal morni...
John reaches school. He is greeted by his teacher.

The above is an example of the type of text Im looking to edit. I've been trying to use regex to match ... and the preceeding . . (example, match everything between ...and the preceeding full stop.
I need to target

This is a normal morni

I can match the ... but its the matching backwards to the full stop I cant get.
When I put that into Google Sheets
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\.(?!.*\. ).*?\.{3}",C2)

it says its not a regular expression, but I can see that it works in regex101.com

Try REGEXPEXTRACT(A2, "\.([^.]*)\.{3}") - which should work IF there are no other dots in the part between the dot and three dots.

That's sorted it  thanks!

I added that to the answer and also added a comment, please check it and if you have more questions, please comment below.

You can use
REGEXPEXTRACT(A2, "\.([^.]*)\.{3}")

See the regex demo.
It should work IF there are no other dots in the part between the dot and three dots.
Details:

\. - a dot
([^.]*) - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than .
\.{3} -  three . chars.


FYI, if you want to also support abbreviations like U.S., you may try another regex like \.((?:(?:\p{Lu}\.)+\B|[^.])*)\.{3}, or \.((?:(?:\p{Lu}\.)+\B|etc\.|[^.])*)\.{3} if you want to add support for etc. and similar abbreviations.

Note that this captures "quick brown dog" in "my..quick brown dog......is named Saffi.",. That  may not be a problem but it illustrates the limitations of regex engines that do not support lookarounds.

Google products use RE2 for regular expressions. You can find the supported RE2 syntax here.
Your attempted solution is using (?!.*\. ), a "negative look-ahead". This is valid in most regex "flavours" (such as PCRE2, which regex101.com uses by default), but it is NOT SUPPORTED by RE2 - and therefore cannot be used in Google sheets.
You need a solution bound by the constraints of the supported syntax, hence why "\.([^.]*)\.{3}" is a working option.

If there may be more than one match and you want to return them all, you can use:
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(?s)\. ([^.]*)\.{3}|.","$1|"),"|")


